# Azure - http request takes a long time

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have small ASP.NET application and everything was ok, but a day ago I noticed:  http request takes a long time (~13-15seconds).

I tried to add simple method to controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/[controller]/test")]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello. I'm ok.";
    }
```

But request takes ~13 seconds.

What I tried and what info I have:

- On local machines (2 different) everething is ok - I don't see any delays.
- Application was deployed on AZURE one week ago, but delays started a day ago.
- Restart doesn't help.
- Redeploing on Azure doesn't help.
- Redeploing on Azure as other service doesn't help.
- Connecting to Azure's DB from locale machne is fast.
- My AZURE's quota is OK.
- List item

**Response time and CPU:**

[image]

**Monitor:**

[image]

Comment: Is this an Azure VM, Azure Cloud Service, or Azure Website, or something else? What Pricing-tier is your resource on? Note that performance is never guaranteed on the "Free" and "Shared" tiers of Azure Websites.

Comment: It is Web App (App Service).
Pricing Tier: Standard: 1 Small

Comment: Does it do anything to the requests, or is it essentially an "empty" API project? Like, is there some authentication or other kinds of request validations?

Comment: @ juunas, no authentication, validation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it.
It was misconfiguration. I used .net core but with Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.
And I used DNX dnx451.

I ported project to net46 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Websites effectively go to sleep if not hit so the startup time of the first request can be slow.

Try hitting your url, time it. Then hit it again.

If the second one is fast, its just because nothing is hitting your application and its going into sleep mode.

Comment: Of course I tried it, but unfortunately every request is slow.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and step through. In Azure (AKA Remote Debugging). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio or better yet, add Application Insights and just wait for it to surface the problem for you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net

Comment: @evilSnobu I don't think that's going to help because the OP's web-service method is trivial (return a string literal) - I think the delays are elsewhere in the system outside the OP's control.

Comment: Yes but that's not debugging, that's just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for idea about sleepeing!
It looks like application goes to sleep after every request!
I checked "Always On" option on AZURE and it helped... a bit.
If I make requests without delay it is ok, but after one minute I have to wait about ~13-15seconds again.